# Flutter Calculator App UI overflowing in most of the devices

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-container

I'm working on a calculator UI in flutter. The code that I have written is rendering perfectly fine but the main trouble I'm having after debugging that code is that the calculator UI is not visible in most of the devices which have low screen resolution like moto g4, galaxy s5, iphone 5 etc. I Have used **MediaQuery** and **SafeArea** widget in my code but that still could not fix it out. [this is the picture of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wdp8.png) that I rendered in moto g4. Here is the code of my calculator UI,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gstcalculator/buttons.dart';
import 'package:gstcalculator/gstbuttons.dart';
    
void main(){
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: GSTCalculatorApp()
    )
  );
}

class GSTCalculatorApp extends StatefulWidget {
  

  @override
  _GSTCalculatorState createState() => _GSTCalculatorState();
}

class _GSTCalculatorState extends State<GSTCalculatorApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "GST Calculator",
      
      home: SafeArea(
        
        child: Scaffold(
          
          
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF13131b),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Center(child: Text('GST Calculator')),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
          ),
        
          body: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *1.0,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.5 ,
        
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: Text('41 x 3', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30,color: Colors.white54),),
                  alignment: Alignment(1.0, 1.0),
                ),
        
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Text('123',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 70),),
                  alignment: Alignment(1.0, 1.0),
                ),
        
                Container(
                  // height: 80,
                  // width: 1000,
                  color: Color(0xFF0f0f0f),
        
                  child: Row(
        
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    
                    children: [
                      
                      
                      Gstbutton(gstbtntext: 'CHECK ➞',),
                      Gstbutton(gstbtntext: 'CORRECT ☒',),
                      Gstbutton(gstbtntext: 'CHANGE GST %',),
                    ],
                  ),
        
                
                  
                  ),
        
                
        
        
        
        
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              
                  children: [
                    Button(btntext: '3%',btntextsize: 20,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
                    Button(btntext: '5%',btntextsize: 20,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
                    Button(btntext: '8%',btntextsize: 20,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
                    Button(btntext: '18%',btntextsize: 18,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
                    Button(btntext: '28%',btntextsize: 18,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
               
                  ],
        
                ),
                
        
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        
                  children: [
                    Button(btntext: '-3%',btntextsize: 20,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
                    Button(btntext: '-5%',btntextsize: 20,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
                    Button(btntext: '-8%',btntextsize: 20,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
                    Button(btntext: '-18%',btntextsize: 15.9,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
                    Button(btntext: '-28%',btntextsize: 15.9,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFF4DE2C8,),
               
                  ],
        
                ),
        
        
        
        
                 Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Button(btntext: '7',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '8',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '9',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: 'C',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '⌫',btntextsize:30,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFD2353B,),
                  ],
                ),
        
                
                 Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Button(btntext: '4',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '5',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '6',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: 'X',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFD2353B,),
                    Button(btntext: '/',btntextsize: 30,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFD2353B,),
                  ],
                ),
        
                 Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Button(btntext: '1',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '2',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '3',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '+',btntextsize: 30,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFD2353B,),
                    Button(btntext: '-',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFD2353B,),
                  ],
                ),
        
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  
        
                  children: [
                    Button(btntext: '0',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '00',btntextsize: 30,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '.',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFFFFFFF,),
                    Button(btntext: '=',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d,btntextcolor: 0xFFD2353B,),
                    Button(btntext: '%',btntextsize: 35,btncolor: 0xFF0d0d0d, btntextcolor: 0xFFD2353B,),
               
                  ],
        
                ),
        
        
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside column replace 3 children containers with  Expanded widgets.

do the same with gstbutton ,wrap the 3 Gst buttons with Expanded widgets.